# Can we execute a .bat file in post build event command line in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, build-automation

Can we execute a .bat file in post build event command line in visual studio?

Comment: Maybe someone more familiar with the subject matter than me could consider editing this into a better question. Topic of meta discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201639/145673)

Answer (score 123):

Sure, here's an example:

```
call "$(SolutionDir)scripts\copyifnewer.bat" "$(SolutionDir)libs\RLPL.Services.CertificateValidator.Basic.dll" "$(TargetDir)RLPL.Services.CertificateValidator.Basic.dll"
call "$(SolutionDir)scripts\copyifnewer.bat" "$(SolutionDir)libs\RLPL.Services.CertificateValidator.Common.dll" "$(TargetDir)RLPL.Services.CertificateValidator.Common.dll"
```

Just be aware of two possible issues you might have:

1. the enclosing double quotes (see how each part is surrounded by `"` sign)
2. if you want to call 2 or more batch files make sure you use `call` command otherwise you'll have a trouble finding why the second bat is not doing its job

Comment: thank you for a note about "call", it solves my problem with multiply executing.

Comment: Even though SO is now asking me to not explain my gratitude: +1 for point 2)

Comment: Might need to change the current directory, as by default it is run within the `Bin` folder. I needed to run inside the solution dir, so for me it was: `call cd $(SolutionDir)` as a first line in Post-build events.

Comment: How do you actually set this up? Does this go in the csproj file?

Answer (score 32):

Yes, by adding a call to it in the post-build event editor.

If you go to the Properties page for your project, you should select the Build Events tab. You can type in the call to your batch file in the *Post-build event command line* text box.

If you want to refer to the batch file using the paths included in the project or solution, you can click on the *Edit Post-Build...* button. This will open the *Post-build Event Command Line* dialog box.

This dialog box has a *Macros >>* button that you can click. It will show you all the available Macros that you can use to refer to folders and files within your solution.

When you select one of those macros, you can use the *Insert* button to insert them into your script.

Comment: +1 but for completeness note divo's comment on Jon Skeet's response re using the macros to specify paths for project-specific batch files.

Comment: The answer referred to above no longer exists. The comment trail was Q. "How do I give the batch file the path?" and the comment in response was A. "You can use either use a hard-coded path, or - better - use the variables available when you click on the "Macros" button. For instance, "$(ProjectDir)" (without the quotes) will be the directory where the Visual Studio project file resides"

Comment: How to do it for entire solution rather than individual project?

Answer (score 9):

As well as calling a .bat file, you can enter batch commands (i.e., the normal commands available from the Windows console--cmd.exe) directly into the Pre-build/Post-build fields. This may be preferable as it means you do not have to maintain the batch file separately, as all your commands will be part of the project.

Comment: It's just as easy to commit the post-build script to SCM right along with your project. Actually it's easier to test, it's versioned right along with your files and it's not buried in project files.

Personally I no real good rationale for (but many against) having anything but a one-line CALL in your post-build action property.