# Can't execute a batch file on post-build

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491394/can-we-execute-a-bat-file-in-post-build-event-command-line-in-visual-studio) but despite different attempts, I get an error (it varies depending on my approach).

The compilation itself works fine. Double-clicking on the "publish.bat" files executes it just fine too. It's the combo in VS10 that breaks.

This is what I've tested.

```
$(OutDir)\publish.bat
"$(OutDir)\publish.bat"
$(OutDir)publish.bat
"$(OutDir)publish.bat"

call $(OutDir)\publish.bat
call "$(OutDir)\publish.bat"
call $(OutDir)publish.bat
call "$(OutDir)publish.bat"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I was just able to fix.  For me the simple `call "$(SolutionDir)\Setup\CreateInstaller.bat"` worked, but I kept getting a `The command "call {solution directory}\Setup\CreateInstaller.bat" exited with code {code}`.  Turns out my batch file was expecting to be run from the directory in which it lived.  So, check that all the commands in the batch file are not using relative directories or commands as these may break.

Also, are you sure the `$(OutDir)` macro is what you want?  In VS2010 at least, that is just equal to `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` depending on which version you're building in.  It seems unlikely that you really want that directory.  I expect what you want is `$(SolutionDir)` or perhaps even `$(TargetDir)`.

Comment: Nice digging up, mate. I'll give it a try when I get some time to spare. As for the placement, I agree with you. In this particular case, it's needed though. Long story including stubborn and less skilled co-worker editing stuff she shouldn't. :)