# Post build event in VS2012..Running a Batch file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build-automation

Am trying to run a Batch file in Post build event in Visual studio.

Referred [Can we execute a .bat file in post build event command line in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491394/can-we-execute-a-bat-file-in-post-build-event-command-line-in-visual-studio) for reference.

When i post the line

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin" "$(SolutionDir)Deploy\bin" /S in postbuild
```

am getting the expected result

Same line i put in bat and tried calling

```
call "$(SolutionDir)\Deploy.bat"
```

or

```
call "Physical path\deploy.bat"
```

Am getting excited with code 1. What am i doing wrong here ?

Can i specify macros inside batch file ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you do in the `deploy.bat`? Are you sure that it does not have an error? Did you try to enable Diagnostics logging from msbuild and see if it will give you more details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting a VS error because it returned an exit code that is not 0. This does not necessarily mean there was an error.

The error code returned means that no files were copied.
These are the return codes for Xcopy:

- Exit Code

  - 0           Files were copied without error.
  - 1           No files were found to copy.
  - 2           The user pressed Ctrl+C to terminate xcopy.
  - 4           Various errors including insufficient memory or disk space, an invalid drive name, or invalid syntax.
  - 5           Disk write error occurred.

Try this code in your batch file. Use the /Y so that you will not have to deal with any prompts. You can handle the return code of 1 with another action or just return 0.

VS Post Build command line code:

`CALL "$(SolutionDir)"Deploy.bat "$(ProjectDir)bin" "$(SolutionDir)Deploy\bin"`

Deploy.bat file

`Xcopy %1 %2 /S /Y`

`If errorlevel 1 @exit 0`