# How can I get Visual Studio to use FAKE for building my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, f#-fake

I'm looking for a solution that invokes my FAKE build script when I do a "Build Solution" (Ctrl + F6). Bonus points for a way to specify a target other than the default.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer but Paket has `paket.targets` file (https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/blob/68969d970bf2d60fb4e280e4365b6f87b9a7e285/.paket/paket.targets) which runs Paket when a solution is built (basically, by running the executable). I'm sure you could do the same for FAKE - but writing that MS Build XML stuff will be pain ...

Comment: Post-build event? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1491413/126014

Comment: I've looked into how Paket does this: they use BuildDependsOn but that wouldn't work for a FAKE script. The FAKE "Build" target, executing itself an MSBuild task, would trigger the FAKE script recursively. I've not yet found a proper way to get this working nicely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest I found so far is to define FAKE as an external tool via

```
 Tools -> External tools...
```

[image: ExternalTool]

Set it to use the output window and to prompt for arguments. Then, define a keyboard shortcut via

```
 Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Tools.ExternalCommand6
```

When you invoke it you can provide a target or just press enter to build the default.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem in another way. It requires manual edit of csproj files and the trick is in conditional override of builtin `Build`, `Clean` and `Rebuild` targets.

First I created custom `fake.targets` file and saved it in `Targets` folder at the solution level:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="packages\FAKE\tools\FAKE.exe build.fsx Build proj=$(ProjectPath) conf=$(Configuration) plat=$(Platform)" WorkingDirectory="..\" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <Exec Command="packages\FAKE\tools\FAKE.exe build.fsx Rebuild proj=$(ProjectPath) conf=$(Configuration) plat=$(Platform)" WorkingDirectory="..\" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <Exec Command="packages\FAKE\tools\FAKE.exe build.fsx Clean proj=$(ProjectPath) conf=$(Configuration) plat=$(Platform)" WorkingDirectory="..\" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Next, at the bottom of `<Project />` section in each `*.csproj` project file I added:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <FakeTargetsPath>..\Targets\fake.targets</FakeTargetsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(FakeTargetsPath)" Condition="Exists($(FakeTargetsPath)) And '$(RealBuild)'!='true'" />
```

**Note:** `FakeTargetsPath` is relative to the `csproj` file.

Last step was to create `build.fsx` that invokes MSBuild with `RealBuild = true`:

```fsharp
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake

let solution = "solution.sln"

let commonBuild target =
    let project = getBuildParamOrDefault "proj" solution
    let configuration = getBuildParamOrDefault "conf" "Release"
    let platform = getBuildParamOrDefault "plat" "AnyCPU"
    let setParams defaults =
        { defaults with
            Verbosity = Some(Quiet)
            Targets = [ target ]
            Properties =
                [
                    "Configuration", configuration
                    "Platform", platform
                    "RealBuild", "true"
                ]
        }

    build setParams project

Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    commonBuild "Build"
)

Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
    commonBuild "Clean"
)

Target "Rebuild" (fun _ ->
    commonBuild "Rebuild"
)

RunTargetOrDefault "Build"
```

Comment: Very interesting. What is the effect if this `RealBuild` option?